# How to use powershell to add a contact to a contact group On outlook 2010

Tags: powershell, outlook, distribution-list, contactgroups

I just created a Distribution list:

```
$outlook = new-object -com Outlook.Application
$contacts = $outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(10)
$dl = $contacts.Items.Add("IPM.DistLIst")
$dl.Save()
```

and then created a new contact

```
$newcontact = $contacts.Items.Add()
$newcontact.FullName = "abc"
$newcontact.JobTitle = "abc manager"
$newcontact.Email1Address = "abc@abc.com"
```

How do I add this new contact to the newly created contact list?

I have tried:

```
$dl.Members.Add($newcontact)
$dl.Action.Add($newcontact)
```

But they both did not work,

Please help, any help will be appreciated.

Ruijie

Answer (score 0):

The [AddMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff864726.aspx) method of the DistListItem class allows to add a new member to the specified distribution list. Note, the distribution list contains Recipient objects that represent valid e-mail addresses, not contacts.

```
 Sub AddNewMember() 
  'Adds a member to a new distribution list 
  Dim objItem As Outlook.DistListItem 
  Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem 
  Dim objRcpnt As Outlook.Recipient 
  Set objMail = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
  Set objItem = Application.CreateItem(olDistributionListItem) 
  'Create recipient for distlist 
  Set objRcpnt = Application.Session.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") 
  objRcpnt.Resolve 
  objItem.AddMember objRcpnt 
  'Add note to list and display 
  objItem.DLName = "Northwest Sales Manager" 
  objItem.Body = "Regional Sales Manager - NorthWest" 
  objItem.Save 
  objItem.Display 
 End Sub
```

See [How To: Create a new distribution list item in Outlook](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/03/29/create-outlook-distribution-list/) for more information.

Comment: So from Powershell, do I call it like this :   $dl.AddMember($newcontact)? sorry I am confused